# I have an array state of my react component, should I use Object.assign() when I add new item? I tried spread operator but see strange behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a functional react component which receives a random **message** object regularly. It displays the new added item properly. After I delete one item and received a new **message**, deleted item remains again. I solved by using **Object.assign()**, but not sure why spread operator is not working.

I think spread operator copies array. I have been using spread operator when adding new item to array state variable. When to use *Object.assign()*, when to use *spread operator*?

Here is my code.

```
const myComp = props => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [api] = useState(new Api({
    messageCallback: (msg) => {
      handleCallback(msg);
    },
  }));

  useEffect(()=>{
    api.start();
  },[])

  const handleCallback = msg => {
    messages.push(msg);
    setMessages([...messages]);
  }

  const deleteItem = index => {
    messages.splice(index,1);
    setMessages([...messages]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
        messages.map((item, index)=>(
          <p key={index} onClick={(e)=>deleteItem(index)}>{item.message}</p>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

This works not properly so I solved by using this.

```
const handleCallback = msg => {
  const temp = Object.assign(messages,[]);
  temp.push(msg);
  setMessages(temp)
}
```

Comment: `Object.assign` is for *objects* not arrays. And mutating state the way you are doing (.push, .splice) is not supported in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code has a number of problems:

- The API initialized on mount with

```
  const [api] = useState(new Api({
    messageCallback: (msg) => {
      handleCallback(msg);
    },
  }));
```

sees the `handleCallback` declared on mount - and that function only has scope of the `messages` that exists on mount, which is an empty array.

- You're mutating the existing state when you do

```
messages.push(msg);
```

Instead, clone the state *before* changing. Same for

```
messages.splice(index,1);
```

To fix all of these, change:

```
  const handleCallback = msg => {
    messages.push(msg);
    setMessages([...messages]);
  }

  const deleteItem = index => {
    messages.splice(index,1);
    setMessages([...messages]);
  }
```

to

```
const handleCallback = msg => {
    setMesesages(
        // use the callback form so that the `messages` argument
        // refers to the most up-to-date state, not the state on mount
        messages => {
            const newMessages = [...messages]; // create shallow copy of state
            // so you don't mutate the existing state
            newMessages.push(msg);
            return newMessages;
        }
    );
};

const deleteItem = index => {
    setMesesages(
        // use the callback form so that the `messages` argument
        // refers to the most up-to-date state, not the state on mount
        messages => {
            const newMessages = [...messages]; // create shallow copy of state
            // so you don't mutate the existing state
            newMessages.splice(index, 1);
            return newMessages;
        }
    );
};
```

Since you probably don't want to call `new Api` more than once, I'd recommend either using the functional version of `useState` (which gets called once, on mount):

```
const [api] = useState(() => new Api({
    messageCallback: (msg) => {
        handleCallback(msg);
    },
}));
```

Or create the API in an effect hook instead. Since the API doesn't look to be used anywhere else in the component, it doesn't need to be stateful at all, I think.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const api = new Api({
        messageCallback: (msg) => {
            handleCallback(msg);
        },
    });
    api.start();
}, []);
```

> When to use Object.assign()

Generally, when you need to make a shallow copy of an object (almost always not an array), eg

```
const shallowCopy = Object.assign({}, someObj);
```

This is identical to using spread syntax in an object:

```
const shallowCopy = { ...someObj };
```

You can also use spread syntax when you want to create a shallow copy of an *array*, like with

```
const newMessages = [...messages];
```

Comment: your answer is helpful, but last code about **useEffect** is not correct. Pls remove it

Comment: Can you tell me about the callback of setState? If you let me know the url of the manual, really helpful.

Comment: Why do you say it's incorrect? The code in your question doesn't use the API anywhere except in the effect hook, so you may as well make it not stateful to avoid confusion and make the code cleaner.

Comment: For the callback form of `useState`, see the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: I used API for other UI, not mentioned in my code. Others are perfect

Answer (score 1):

Operations like this mutate the array in place, and should be avoided with state values as there could be unexpected side-effects:

```
messages.push(msg);
```

Instead, create the new array when setting the state:

```
const handleCallback = msg => {
  setMessages([...messages, msg]);
}
```

The same can be done when removing an element:

```
const deleteItem = index => {
  setMessages([...messages.filter((m, i) => i !== index)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not about spreading but how you set your states.

You are supposed to set the state using setState, i.e. setMessages instead of mutating it (messages) directly like what you did here:

```
  const handleCallback = msg => {
    messages.push(msg); //here you try to mutate the state messages by .push
    setMessages([...messages]);
  }

  const deleteItem = index => {
    messages.splice(index,1); //here you try to mutate the state messages by .splice
    setMessages([...messages]);
  }
```

Changing these 2 functions as below is one of the ways to make your code work:

```
 const handleCallback = msg => {
    setMessages([...messages, msg]);
  }

  const deleteItem = index => {
    setMessages([...messages.filter((v,i) => i !== index)]); //note that .filter does not mutate "messages" but creates a new array
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, many developers are adding a new item by the DOM event. In my app, it is automatically added by the API without rendering the UI. That was the problem.
https://thecodebarbarian.com/object-assign-vs-object-spread.html

**Spread operator** also copies the array but have different value though original value changes. When you use **Object.assign**, copied value has the same value when original value changes.

In my app, when I use spread operator, message variable remains the original empty value though it seems to change.